# Why does ifstream read() behave differently in two different programs?

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

I'm trying to write a program that reads in an OpenGL shader from a .txt file. I've actually already done this a few days ago, this was the code I used:

```
char vShaderData[2000];
char fShaderData[2000];
void readShaders() {
    std::ifstream vShaderF;
    std::ifstream fShaderF;
    vShaderF.open("shaders//vertexShader.txt");
    fShaderF.open("shaders//fragShader.txt");
    if (vShaderF.is_open() && fShaderF.is_open()) std::cout << m << "Shader read success" << std::endl; 
    else std::cout << "Shader read fail" << std::endl; 
    std::cout << m << "vertex shader: " << std::endl;
    vShaderF.read(vShaderData, 2000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        std::cout << vShaderData[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << m << "frag shader: " << std::endl;
    fShaderF.read(fShaderData, 2000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        std::cout << fShaderData[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    vShaderF.close();
    fShaderF.close();
}
```

This worked great. my shader file was not actually not 2000 in length, but the `read()` call seemed to store the extra characters as whitespace into the char array which is what I wanted.

Now having restructured my code a little bit in a newer program, my reader now looks like this:

```
    std::ifstream shaderFile;
    shaderFile.open(path);  
    if (shaderFile.is_open()) cout << "Shader at: " << path << ", initalized" << endl;
    char data[2000];
    shaderFile.read(data, 2000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) std::cout << data[i];
```

The actual text portion still reads correct. However, now the extra space in the char array is stored with this instead of whitespace: 
[image]

In case the image won't show, it is basically just a reapeating pattern of these two characters `[|[|[|...`.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

NOTE: I'm using the same shader file, same computer, same IDE, same everything. The old one still works.

Comment: Well, one thing that's different is how global arrays are initialized vs ones  allocated locally.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ah yup that did it. I just changed my array to global and it filled w/ whitespace. Thank you. Sorry for such a silly and simple question, I don't know much C++. I mostly do java,

Comment: In C/C++ instancing a scalar type will not initialize it (performance reasons), so doing `int a;` in a function means, that `a` can have any value (what was there on the stack). Global variables are exception, initialized to type default value (for `int` it's `0`). In Java you will always receive initialized instance of everything (that's reason #1234345 why Java is slow when compared to properly written C/C++, and that's irrelevant in real life, as almost nobody knows to write proper C/C++ (at least I don't))

Comment: @Ped7g nope you are spot on: pretty much nobody knows how to write proper C xD. This is why I stick with high level languages. C and Assembly scare the crap outta me!

Comment: Don't be scared of Assembly, it's not 1985, that you would be able to burn the screen by accidentally outputting wrong frequency on graphics card control register. Today it's mostly harmless, and OS are well protected. You wouldn't believe how many times I lost my source on ZX because I forgot to save it to tape before trying it out (not as much forgot, as I was so sure it will work this time, without resetting the ZX, that I was just lazy to wait those 15-20s to save it). Now it's like total breeze, with debuggers available and virtual machines, etc... I had to do most of my debug on paper.

Comment: @Ped7g lol fair enough. I suppose I should give it a proper shot. Its not just that I'm afraid of hardware damage though, I also have a horrible understanding of low level memory allocation and stuff. But, like you said, its not 1985 (heck, i was born in the 2000s) so I shouldn't be afraid of Assembely at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `std::istream:read()` it will **not** set the parts of the buffer to spaces which were not read. The memory will be left untouched. If you want to get spaces into an unread area of the buffer, you'll need to put the spaces there yourself. If the program indeed had spaces in the buffer it was because the buffer somehow already contained spaces by chance.

You can use `std::istream::gcount()` to determine how many characters were read.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the arrays to contain predefined data, you'll have to initialize it with such predefined data. If the stream reads fewer data than the array size, you will have the padding you want.